# Missing $ inserted error in matrix code

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I am attaching a piece of matrix code which is giving the "Missing $ inserted error" on the lines where matrix is starting and ending.

```
\begin{pmatrix}
    E_{1}& T_{1}& 0& 0& \cdots& 0& 0\\
    T_{1}& E_{2}& T_{2}& 0& \cdots& 0& 0\\
    0& T_{2}& E_{3}& T_{3}& \cdots& 0& 0\\
    \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots&\vdots& \vdots\\
    0& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& E_{N-1}& T_{N-1}\\
    0& 0& 0& 0& \cdots& T_{N-1}& E_{N}\\
\end{pmatrix}
```

I am using only amsmath and physics package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). The `pmatrix` needs to be in math mode. So use `\[ \begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix} \]`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it

Comment: @PeterGrill, the complete document is several pages long. Wouldn't it make the question more messier? It would become difficult for the reader. Anyway, thanks for the tip! Solved my problem.

Comment: @PulkitAditya the point is not to post the _original_ document but a small document which generates the error, so you should have added `\documentstyle{article}`, `\begin{document}` and a minimal number of packages so that people can use the example and see the error or output that you are asking about.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, duly noted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just missing math environment, solved by OP in comments